# How to properly set height on GRID?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I trying to create a UI something just like this (as a reference).

[image: Image 1]

but I am having a trouble to get the design. I used grid but I keep getting this result. I set the Grid row definitions to 80* and 20* and still not getting the result I wanted. My idea is the design to be in percentage rather that set a specific height. If I can't use percentage is there a way to make my UI responsive for different screen size and orientation? Is there a way I can achieve this?

[image: Image 2]

Here is my XAML Code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Spacing="0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="80*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" StyleClass="start" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Label StyleClass="brand" Text="TBS">
                            <Label.FontFamily>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                    <On Platform="Android" Value="SFProDisplay-Black.ttf#SFProDisplay-Black"/>
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </Label.FontFamily>
                        </Label>
                        <Label StyleClass="startpagetitle" Text="TBS Point of Sale">
                            <Label.FontFamily>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                    <On Platform="Android" Value="SFProDisplay-Light.ttf#SFProDisplay-Light"/>
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </Label.FontFamily>
                        </Label>
                        <Label StyleClass="startpagesubtitle" Text="Run and grow your business.">
                            <Label.FontFamily>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                    <On Platform="Android" Value="SFProDisplay-Light.ttf#SFProDisplay-Light"/>
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </Label.FontFamily>
                        </Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Button StyleClass="btn" Text="Login" x:Name="btnLogin">
                        <Button.FontFamily>
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                <On Platform="Android" Value="SFProDisplay-Regular.ttf#SFProDisplay-Regular"/>
                            </OnPlatform>
                        </Button.FontFamily>
                    </Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: get rid of all the unnecessary nested layout containers.  Just create a grid with three rows.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the StackLayout outside of your content Grid. The Grid won't take the whole space of the `StackLayout` so that it looks the percentage is wrong:

```
<ScrollView>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="80*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" StyleClass="start" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Label StyleClass="brand" Text="TBS">
                    <Label.FontFamily>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="SFProDisplay-Black.ttf#SFProDisplay-Black"/>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Label.FontFamily>
                </Label>
                <Label StyleClass="startpagetitle" Text="TBS Point of Sale">
                    <Label.FontFamily>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="SFProDisplay-Light.ttf#SFProDisplay-Light"/>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Label.FontFamily>
                </Label>
                <Label StyleClass="startpagesubtitle" Text="Run and grow your business.">
                    <Label.FontFamily>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                            <On Platform="Android" Value="SFProDisplay-Light.ttf#SFProDisplay-Light"/>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Label.FontFamily>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Button StyleClass="btn" Text="Login" x:Name="btnLogin">
                <Button.FontFamily>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                        <On Platform="Android" Value="SFProDisplay-Regular.ttf#SFProDisplay-Regular"/>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Button.FontFamily>
            </Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

Moreover, I think the scroll view can be removed too if you don't want your screen to scroll.

Or you can try to add `<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">` to make your Grid fill full of the `StackLayout`.